# string interpolation Vue js

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to combine a string and a prop to create a unique `id` for a bootstrap accordion.

I want to combine "collapse" and {{ thread_ref }} to create something like: `id="collapse_321"`

Vue gives me an error when I try to do this and says to use v-bind.

I have tried that but that only accepts a string of the name of the prop/data, how can I combine a string and data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `inline` it as stated  by Vamsi, but you can also use a `computed`, which has a bit of a neater syntax:

**Markup**

```
<div :id="collapse_id"></div>
```

**View Model**

```
computed: {
  collapse_id() {
    return 'collapse_' + this.thread_ref
  }
},
```

However, that relies on `thread_ref` being available in `data`, here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j9s3zhp2/

If it being placed inside a `v-for` you can achieve the same with a `method`:

**Markup**

```
<div v-for="ref in refs"> 
  <div :id="collapse_id(ref)"></div>
</div>
```

**View Model**

```
methods:{
  collapse_id(thread_ref){
    return 'collapse_' + thread_ref
  }
}
```

And here's the JSFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/5o1dp7w5/

Answer (score 15):

Do it like this:

```
:id="'collape' + thread_ref"
```

Anything inside the `" "` when you bind a property using `v-bind` or `:` is javascript. So you can do any single line expressions that you do in JavaScript

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems so obvious now that you have pointed it out, I feel dumb :P